# How do I store only the number values in a 2d array from a given input file? (no pointers)

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the following file using C++

> Johnson 60 12.50
>   Aniston 65 13.25
>   Cooper 50 14.50
>   Gupta 70 14.75
>   Blair 55 10.50
>   Clark 40 18.75
>   Kennedy 45 20.50
>   Bronson 60 20.00
>   Sunny 65 18.75
>   Smith 30 9.75

I can read the names fine, but I'm having trouble reading the rest of the line. As you can see, the names can be any length but the longest is 7 characters. Since I'm trying to read into a 2d array of doubles, I've remedied this by ignoring the first 7 characters of the line; however, when I print the contents of the array it appears to be printing memory addresses.

I have no idea how to fix this issue with out the use of pointers. `store_names` works perfectly, and after it's ran the output window contains the correct names. The problem is where I have:

```
read.ignore(7, '\n');
read >> payment[i][j];
cout << payment[j];
```

It just prints memory addresses. How can I read the two numbers after the name into my `payment` array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream read;
ofstream write;

void store_names(string a [10])
{
    string storage;
    read.open("Data.txt"); //open file
    if (read.is_open()==true)// check to see if file is open
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            read >> a[i];
            read.ignore(256, '\n');//store file string into array
            cout << a[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}

void store_payments(double payment [10][3])
{
    read.open("Data.txt");
    if (read.is_open() == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                read.ignore(7, '\n');
                read >> payment[i][j];
                cout << payment[j];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string name_array[10];
    double payment[10][3];
    store_names(name_array);
    store_payments(payment);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. I recommend removing the assignment part because it's not relevant. You should [edit] your question to describe clearly what you're trying to read (read numbers from a file, where the numbers come after a name) and store those number. You should describe what about your current code is not working. Is there a compiler error, or does it run and not store anything? Or does it store most things except one? You should also endeavour to fix any formatting issues with your code. There's no reason not to have properly formatted code, anything else scares people away

Comment: Hey thank you. I have edited the question in accordance with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `store_payments`, `read` is already open and at the end of the file (assuming those are the only things in the file, I will assume they are). Your next read is invalid, because you're at the end of the file and there's nothing else to read. You should endeavour to check the state of the read afterwards, and you would see this:

```
read.ignore(7, '\n');
if (read.good())
{
    read >> payments[i][j];
}
```

You could also see this behaviour by checking `eof()`:

```
void store_payments(double payment[10][3])
{
    read.open("Data.txt");
    if (read.eof())
    {
        read.clear(); // clear the eof flag
        read.seekg(0, ios::beg); // return to top of the file
    }
}
```

Or you could just close the file at the end of `store_names`.

When you call `read.ignore(7, '\n')`, 7 characters will be ignored. This will work fine for the first two names, which are 7 characters long, but if you encounter a name that isn't, you'll attempt to read something that isn't a `double`. Again, you would've seen this if you were checking the state of `read` after each read:

```
read.ignore(7, '\n');
if (read.good())
{
}
```

Since your names can be variable length, you should read the entire line first, then sift through it. You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to do this:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(read, line);
```

Now `line` will contain something like

> Johnson 60 12.50

You can just use [`std::string` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to remove the non-numeric parts, or look for whitespace. You could combine both functions together, and assume the name is everything to the first space, the *something* is everything to the next white space, and the *something else* is everything else.

The reason you are seeing memory addresses in your print, is because you're printing memory addresses.

```
cout << payment[j];
```

`payment[j]` is essentially a pointer to the first element in `payment`. You likely meant to print `payment[i][j]` instead.